# how to flatmap the arrays out of rust arrays

Tags: rust

```
struct Epos(u8);

struct Pos(u8);

pub const ALL_EPOS: [Epos; 8] = [
    Epos(1),
    Epos(2),
    Epos(3),
    Epos(4),
    Epos(5),
    Epos(6),
    Epos(7),
    Epos(8),
];

pub const ALL_POS: [Pos; 64] =
    ALL_EPOS.flat_map(|file|
                 ALL_EPOS.map(|rank|
                              Pos::new(file, rank)));

impl Pos {

    fn new(file: Epos, rank: Epos) -> Pos {
        Pos(file.0 * 8 + rank.0)
    }
}
```

I can't make an `ALL_POS` array of Pos, using `ALL_EPOS` array of Epos. `flat_map` it gives this error:

```
25 |         ALL_EPOS.flat_map(|file|
   |                  ^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `[Epos; 8]` due to unsatisfie
d trait bounds
```

Comment: You need to call `.into_iter()` or `.iter()`. However, this cannot be done in const context anyway.

Comment: And you would also need to `collect()` the result, but I'm not sure that this works for arrays…

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b4e9f2f41e17a34fe962c7ea8f6bbc14)

Comment: So what is the idiomatic way to get a global list of all positions so I can iterate over them everywhere.

Comment: https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.9.0/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html or https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/

Comment: I would recomment once_cell more since its API is going to be part of std.